# What does a body visible to the human eye moving at constant speed look like in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, many-body

In regular $QM$ A single particle is going to have a wave function that solves the free schrodinger equation of energy and momentum such that $$dE/dp = v$$.

Obviously the sense of nearness of particles are relative, but what I am thinking of is the quantum field analysis of an object that would be visible to a human being. I suspect statistical notions might enter, which I do not object to, but certainly the $QFT$ must possess some certain statistical properties that cause the object to be perceived as a body moving at a speed $v$.

I realize in an aggregate system there are many things to consider, such as the properties of the aggregate i.e. intermolecular forces, going all the way down to the standard model Lagrangian. I don't think I need to see that much detail, but I am interested in what properties of the equations, whether the Lagrangian or the quantum field itself, would have that are  most important in all of the particles harmonizing to travel at the same speed. There must be some connection to the group velocity formula as in regular QM.

- Is this even possible, has anyone does this, or is the standard model and $QFT$ really just been limited to particle interactions of a small number?

I believe this touches, if not enters statistical physics and maybe solid-state physics, which is fine but I am most interested in the quantum level description with respect to the *(relativistic)* field theory.

I don't need necessarily the most complete answer, but I am looking for some intuition to guide me into a deeper study of this question. I have studied $QM$, relativistic $QM$, and some very basic field theory and Standard Model at the level of McMahon's book $QFT$ Demystified. Unfortunately I have not studied statistical physics, but would appreciate some guidance as to what to study to find the answer to my question.